# How to make bonding using mobile broadband 4g dongles

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, networkmanager, ppp, bonding

Actually I did connect both ppp0 and ppp1 using nm-connection-editor(network connection setting).

[image]

But now I wish to make a balance-rr(mode 0), and thought that bonding would do that for me. I need to know if its possible, because when I'm searching, I only see people bonding Ethernet interfaces.

When I tried to use bond using nm-connection-editor.

[image]

[image]

When i click Add button

[image]

There is no option to add mobile broadband interfaces inside.

Is bonding capable of dealing with ppp0 and ppp1 mobile broadband 4g dongles? How?

Comment: You can't, unless your ISP supports this configuration. Bonding is a Layer 2 concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my comment implied, you can't bond such connections.

Bonding is a layer 2 concept, ideally invisible to the higher layers. This means that packets addressed to your IP may appear at both interfaces, scheduled by the device sending the frames to you.

However, with your connection to the ISP you have two different L3 devices, which have different IP's and may even be in different subnets.

To do bonding, the other end has to support it as well. Your ISP needs to explicitly configure it.

What you can do is load balancing at the L3 level. This basically means configuring two equal routes, but it may produce strange results as IP's may change suddenly. It's better to send different types of traffic via different routes, or route based on source.

Comment: There are also third-party tunnel services which can aggregate multiple connections, *e.g.* [OverTheBox](https://github.com/ovh/overthebox). The ones I know of are rather expensive for individuals.

Comment: Yes, that's definitively a possibility. There's many things one *can* do, but bonding is *not* one of them.

Comment: Oh, yes, I’m not disagreeing with you!

Comment: We are trying to increase our through put for the IoT device we are building. What other methods do you recommend?

Comment: Will this work if I make the 4G usb dongle work as a WWAN interface? Earlier we were able to bond 2 3G dongles that worked as eth0 and eth1 interface.

Comment: You may have been able to bond them on your end, but I'm willing to bet some money that they didn't actually operate as a proper bond. Furthermore, 4G gives ~100Mb or so in good coverage, which should probably be enough for most IOT applications?

Comment: We couple a IOT application with a wifi hotspot. Hence the need for good bandwidth.

Comment: Then you should probably look into a load balancing tunnel solution as described by @StephenKitt, or a round-robin routing solution (e.g. every n outgoing connection is routed device n, etc)

Comment: @Thoht and please add information explaining what the question is about and what you are actually trying to do (your X in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is "we want to increase throughput", your Y is "we need to to bonding") to the *question* by editing it. Comments are not guaranteed to stick around.